# When main exits, do goroutines run defer()?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine, defer-keyword

If I have a goroutine, can I close a channel I have open on that goroutine using something like this?

`defer(close())`

Or are defer statements not run for goroutines when main exits?

Comment: you must synchronize the program exit sequence.

Comment: When main exits the channel is gone, so closing it during exit is superfluous.

Comment: `defer` statements in not main go routines are not executed when main terminates. When main terminates, all other running go routines are interrupted and terminated on the stop. They don’t execute `defer` instructions. Note that it’s not needed to close channels when main terminates.

Comment: First thing to understand: *goroutines never run defer()* `defer()` is run when a function exits, which is not at all the same as when an goroutine exits.

Comment: @Flimzy, but when you start a goroutine, go explicitly requires it be a function call. Even if you use `go func`  you have to end it with parentheses `go func {...}()`

Comment: @DallinM.: Yes, but that goroutine could then run any number of functions, up to and including an infinite number. And each of those functions could have its own `defer`.  `defer` is a function-scoped feature. It has absolutely nothing to do with goroutines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't. Once `main` done, the whole program is terminated. So you have to manually synchronize graceful termination, if you do need one. There are neat patterns, but that's another story.

And yet it seems that you don't need closing at all. It is fine to keep chanels open, they are totally managed resources and will eventually be garbage-collected. Closing is more a design/intention act rather then a necessary cleanup.

P.S. If you `defer something()` at the `main`'s level, then indeed `something` will get executed after `main` returned. You may rely on this behavior.

Comment: They're talking about closing on exit, so no, they won't be garbage collected. They'll just disappear, like everything else in memory when the application exits.

Comment: @Adrian, sure, I addressed a broader scope just to clarify `chan`'s nature.